# How to pass string variable to php function?

Tags: php, exec, argument-passing

I am using exec() to execute the file. One of the argument I need to pass is string.

`shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client "Hi hello"');` This works fine!

But when I take string into var i.e. $s="Hi hello" and

```
'shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client . "$s"')`. It does not works. If

'shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client . $s')' goes in infinite wait!
```

Any Idea how to pass $s to the function?

Comment: Basic php syntax rules: `'`-quoted strings do **NOT** interpret variables. you're passing a literal `$` and `s` to the shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client "'.$s.'"');
```

or use double quotes to parse variables

```
shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '$s'");
```

or

```
shell_exec("/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client \"$s\"");
```

Comment: I think `$s` needs to be between escaped double quotes too, judging the working command. This evaluates to `shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client Hi Hello');` for both.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) command

```
shell_exec('/home/technoworld/Videos/LinSocket/client '.escapeshellarg($s));
```